# Certificate subject for doesn't contain a common name and does not have alternative names

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have generated a SSL self-signed certificate using the following commands one-by-one in remote ubuntu machine via terminal:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:gsahdg -out server.pass.key 4096
openssl rsa -passin pass:gsahdg -in server.pass.key -out server.key
rm server.pass.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr (in this step, provided the Common Name)
openssl x509 -signkey server.key -in server.csr -req -days 358000 -out server.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt
```

T
I've added the `server.crt` onto my local machine's cacerts using keytool in command prompt as admin. Also added the `server.crt` onto 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities'. he issue is that HTTPS request to the remote ubuntu machine server on Postman works fine but not on IntelliJ with rest-assured as I'm getting:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate subject for  doesn't contain a common name and does not have alternative names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated the .crt & .pfx with common name as remote ubuntu machine ip address and configured the same certificate in the app running. Now that issue has been eradicated.